# Why can't I use std::is_same in std::enable_if?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, template-specialization, compile-time

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

class specialCase {};

template<typename T>
class classTemplate
{
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T,specialCase>::value,void>::type foo()
    {}

    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T,specialCase>::value,void>::type foo()
    {}
};
```

GCC throws an ambiguous error:
error: 'typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_same::value), void>::type classTemplate::foo()' cannot be overloaded with 'typename std::enable_if::value, void>::type classTemplate::foo()'

Why though? As far as I know std::is_same is compile-time and only one of those functions will be compiled for a class template with type T since T is either the special case or it is not.
I am probably misunderstanding something basic about how enable_if works. Can somebody help me?

Comment: `enable_if` needs to depend on a template parameter for `foo`. I'm sure there is a duplicate, I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed it by adding dummy template argument like this: template<class U=T>